# Present and Dismiss with different modal styles

Tags: ios, swift, uimodaltransitionstyle

I want to be able to present a viewController with crossDissolve but dismiss it with the traditional top to bottom dismissal. 
Is there a way to change the modalTransitionStyle once the viewController has opened?

Here is how I am currently presenting

I want to be able to present a viewController with crossDissolve but dismiss it with the traditional top to bottom dismissal. 
Is there a way to change the modalTransitionStyle once the viewController has opened?

Here is how I am currently presenting

```
 let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let userSearchController = UserSearchController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        userSearchController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        currentController?.present(userSearchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: try setting it in the completion

Comment: Perfect, this solution works

Answer (score 0):

Using @Jason's comment I did the following

```
        userSearchController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    currentController?.present(userSearchController, animated: true, completion: {
        userSearchController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    })
```

and it works perfectly